# "MonadReader (Foo m) m" results in infinite type from functional dependency

Tags: haskell, types, monads, monad-transformers

I am trying to pass a function in a Reader that is to be called from the same monad as the calling function, but I get an infinite type error.

The simplified code is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module G2 where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Reader

data Foo m = Foo { bar :: m () }

runFoo :: MonadReader (Foo m) m => m ()
runFoo = do
    b <- asks bar
    b

main :: Monad m => m ()
main = do
    let bar = return () :: m ()
        foo = Foo bar
    runReaderT runFoo foo
```

And the error is:

```
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
        m0 ~ ReaderT (Foo m0) m
        arising from a functional dependency between:
          constraint ‘MonadReader
                        (Foo (ReaderT (Foo m0) m)) (ReaderT (Foo m0) m)’
            arising from a use of ‘runFoo’
          instance ‘MonadReader r (ReaderT r m1)’ at <no location info>
    • In the first argument of ‘runReaderT’, namely ‘runFoo’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: runReaderT runFoo foo
      In the expression:
        do let bar = ...
               foo = Foo bar
           runReaderT runFoo foo
    • Relevant bindings include main :: m () (bound at G2.hs:16:1)
   |
19 |     runReaderT runFoo foo
   |                ^^
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You have `ScopedTypeVariables` enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
runFoo :: MonadReader (Foo m) m => m ()
```

Let's forget about the class, and just assume that `MonadReader env mon` means that `mon ~ ((->) env)`. This corresponds to simply using `(->)` as our monad instead of the fancier `ReaderT`. Then you get `m ~ ((->) m) => m ()`. You see that `m` needs to contain itself (specifically, the argument to `m` is `m`). This is OK for values, but it would be quite bad if the typechecker had to deal with infinitely large types. The same is true for `ReaderT` (and you need to use `ReaderT` because you call `runReaderT runFoo`). You need to define another newtype to encode this recursion:

```
data RecReader c a = RecReader { runRecReader :: c (RecReader c) -> a }
instance Functor (RecReader c) where
  fmap f (RecReader r) = RecReader $ f . r
instance Applicative (RecReader c) where
 pure = RecReader . const
 RecReader f <*> RecReader g = RecReader $ \e -> f e (g e)
instance Monad (RecReader c) where
  return = pure
  RecReader x >>= f = RecReader $ \e -> runRecReader (f (x e)) e
instance MonadReader (c (RecReader c)) (RecReader c) where
  ask = RecReader id
  local f (RecReader x) = RecReader $ x . f
```

And it works:

```
runRecReader runFoo (Foo $ return ())
-- ==>
()
```